# Error with running mysql cookbook on Fedora

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, fedora

I am trying to run openstack-chef-cookbooks (https://github.com/stackforge/openstack-chef-repo) on Fedora 19. Now when I run chef-client, here is the error I am getting:

```
Recipe: openstack-ops-database::mysql-server
  * mysql_database[FLUSH PRIVILEGES] action query
================================================================================
Error executing action `query` on resource 'mysql_database[FLUSH PRIVILEGES]'
================================================================================


Mysql::Error
------------
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:83:in `new'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:83:in `db'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:78:in `exists?'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:64:in `action_query'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/openstack-ops-database/recipes/mysql-server.rb

 61: mysql_database 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' do
 62:   connection mysql_connection_info
 63:   sql 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES'
 64:   action :query
 65: end
 66: 



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/openstack-ops-database/recipes/mysql-server.rb:61:in `from_file'

mysql_database("FLUSH PRIVILEGES") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Database::Mysql
  action [:query]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  database_name "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
  cookbook_name "openstack-ops-database"
  recipe_name "mysql-server"
  connection {:host=>"localhost", :username=>"root", :password=>"pvuOEKmGYLDfzL3cWlSe"}
  sql "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
end



[2014-03-06T02:00:20-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-03-06T02:00:20-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-03-06T02:00:20-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 1 resources updated
[2014-03-06T02:00:21-05:00] ERROR: mysql_database[FLUSH PRIVILEGES] (openstack-ops-database::mysql-server line 61) had an error: Mysql::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[2014-03-06T02:00:21-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I know that Fedora has moved from mysql to mariadb and I have made the appropriate changes. Now, I have mariadb, mariadb-devel and mariadb-server installed. Though I have been told that these cookbooks aren't fully compatible with Fedora, I would still like to get few pointers about how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I've updated your formatting. Please make sure to format stacktraces

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear - you don't have the correct permissions. Did you follow the cookbook instructions and set the `mysql_root_password` attribute?